# Swift Cocoapod - How to use - MTSlideToOpen?

Tags: swift

I am new on Swift.
I want to add one slider on my project but I didn't figure out how.
I installed the Cocoapod MTSlideToOpen imported on my project and I can't use. There is no documentation for it.

The only "Usage" on github is:

```swift
let slide = MTSlideToOpenView(frame: CGRect(x: 26, y: 400, width: 317, height: 56))
slide.sliderViewTopDistance = 6
slide.sliderCornerRadious = 22
slide.delegate = self
slide.defaultLabelText = "Slide To Unlock"
slide.thumnailImageView.image = ic_arrow
```

But where should I add this?

I used the SwiftUI version and worked, but my project is UIkit.

Comment: https://github.com/search?q=MTSlideToOpenView&type=code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used that module, but I deduce `MTSlideToOpenView(frame: CGRect(x: 26, y: 400, width: 317, height: 56))` returns a `UIView` subclass. So far you have only configured it, so you need to add it to the view like this:

```
self.view.addSubview(slide)
```

Comment: worked. But i needed to add the Source File to my project and copy and paste some code to my project. Now i will try to clean up a bit